# sql oracle - filter query sql using case when

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the below query

```
select
    ens.ID_ENS,
    ens.NOM_ENS,
    
   -- for the first SURVEILLANT
    disp.SALLE_EXAM,
    disp.NB_HEURES_ENS,

    -- for the second SURVEILLANT
    disp.SALLE_EXAM2,
    disp.NB_HEURES_ENS2

from ESP_ENSEIGNANT ens, ESP_MODULE_PANIER_CLASSE_SAISO disp
WHERE ens.ID_ENS IN (disp.SURVEILLANT, disp.SURVEILLANT2) AND ens.NOM_ENS != 'A AFFECTER';
```

I want update the query for display SALLE_EXAM, NB_HEURES_ENS only for SURVEILLANT

```
select
    ens.ID_ENS,
    ens.NOM_ENS,

    CASE
        WHEN ens.ID_ENS = disp.SURVEILLANT THEN (disp.SALLE_EXAM AS "EXAM", disp.NB_HEURES_ENS AS "HOURDISP")
        WHEN ens.ID_ENS = disp.SURVEILLANT2 THEN (disp.SALLE_EXAM2 AS "EXAM", disp.NB_HEURES_ENS2 AS "HOURDISP")
    END

from ESP_ENSEIGNANT ens, ESP_MODULE_PANIER_CLASSE_SAISO disp
WHERE ens.ID_ENS IN (disp.SURVEILLANT, disp.SURVEILLANT2) AND ens.NOM_ENS != 'A AFFECTER';
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  Why aren't you using proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rewrite the query with explicit `JOIN` syntax as

```
SELECT ens.ID_ENS,
       ens.NOM_ENS,      
       CASE
         WHEN ens.ID_ENS = disp.SURVEILLANT THEN
           disp.SALLE_EXAM 
         WHEN ens.ID_ENS = disp.SURVEILLANT2 THEN
           disp.SALLE_EXAM2
       END AS "EXAM",
       CASE
         WHEN ens.ID_ENS = disp.SURVEILLANT THEN
          disp.NB_HEURES_ENS 
         WHEN ens.ID_ENS = disp.SURVEILLANT2 THEN
          disp.NB_HEURES_ENS2
       END AS "HOURDISP"
  FROM ESP_ENSEIGNANT ens
  JOIN ESP_MODULE_PANIER_CLASSE_SAISO disp
    ON ens.ID_ENS IN (disp.SURVEILLANT, disp.SURVEILLANT2)
   AND ens.NOM_ENS != 'A AFFECTER';
```

A side note : *if `disp.SURVEILLANT` and `disp.SURVEILLANT2` have equal values, then `disp.SALLE_EXAM` and `disp.NB_HEURES_ENS` will be picked respectively. Eg the first components have precedence.*